# Python3 on Windows error: SyntaxError: multiple statements found while compiling a single statement

Tags: python, python-3.6

I have checked the indents and syntax. I don't understand why it won't execute the module:

```
import operator
def readStudentDetails():
    print("Enter the number of students: ")
    numberOfStudents = int(input)
    studentRecord = {}
    for student in range(0, numberOfStudents):
        print("Enter the name of the student: ")
        name = input()
        print("Enter the marks of students: ")
        marks = int(input)
        studentRecord[name]=marks
    return studentRecord

def rankStudents(studentRecord):
    sortedStudentRecord = sorted(studentRecord.items(), key = operator.itemgetter(1))
    print(sortedStudentRecord)

readStudentDetails()
```

Comment: Please share the entire error message.

Comment: That was the full message.

Comment: How come? All the similar errors I've ever seen included a traceback. As an aside, variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Comment: I just attempted to run your code and I got a TypeError, not a SyntaxError: _Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ad_hoc_3.py", line 18, in <module>
    readStudentDetails()
  File "ad_hoc_3.py", line 4, in readStudentDetails
    numberOfStudents = int(input)
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'builtin_function_or_method'_

Comment: Removed unnecessary information

Comment: SyntaxError: multiple statements found while compiling a single statement